# BigQuery Insert into Nested records

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery, insert, nested-table

I have a table that has a nested record (please see attached snapshot).

[image: schema defination]

I am trying to do a simple insert but it's not working.

```
INSERT  INTO `my_project.my_dataset.test_table`(name,address,comments)
values( 
'my_name' as name,
  [STRUCT('ABC' as line1,'XYZ' as line2,10 as code),
   STRUCT('PQR' as line1,'STU' as line2,20 as code)],
   'Comment')
```

Any idea what's wrong with this SQL insert statement?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't assign names in `values`.  Try:

```
INSERT  INTO `my_project.my_dataset.test_table`(name,address,comments)
    values('my_name',
           [STRUCT('ABC' as line1,'XYZ' as line2,10 as code),
            STRUCT('PQR' as line1,'STU' as line2,20 as code)],
           'Comment'
          )
```

Or use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into `my_project.my_dataset.test_table`(name,address,comments)
    select 'my_name' as name,
           [STRUCT('ABC' as line1,'XYZ' as line2,10 as code),
            STRUCT('PQR' as line1,'STU' as line2,20 as code)],
           'Comment';
```

Comment: It didn't work. I am getting following error `Query column 2 has type ARRAY<STRUCT<line1 STRING, line2 STRING, code INT64>> which cannot be inserted into column address, which has type STRUCT<line1 STRING, line2 STRING, code INT64> at [95:5]:`

Comment: My understanding is that we are inserting an array of Structs but BigQuery seems to think differently. In both of the above cases, BigQuery gives an error, however,nested records in select statement is exactly what I am after.

Comment: @Dinesh. . . I missed that.  You need to make the record `REPEATABLE`.  Right now, it does not contain an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff , that soved the issue

Answer (score 3):

Consider changing `address` Mode to `REPEATED`:

[image]

Also `as name` needs to be removed:

```
INSERT  INTO `my_project.my_dataset.test_table`(name, address, comments)
values('my_name',
       [STRUCT('ABC','XYZ',10), STRUCT('PQR','STU',20)],
       'Comment'
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way that I can enter data in **address.code**  using insert statement. eg:

Something like that:

```
insert into `my_project.my_dataset.test_table`(name,address.code) select myname,[STRUCT('ABC')] from tab1
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31391216)